# How to split the string more efficiently?

Tags: c#, .net, json, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a JSON string which looks like:

```
{"Detail": [
  {"PrimaryKey":111,"Date":"2016-09-01","Version":"7","Count":2,"Name":"Windows","LastAccessTime":"2016-05-25T21:49:52.36Z"},
  {"PrimaryKey":222,"Date":"2016-09-02","Version":"8","Count":2,"Name":"Windows","LastAccessTime":"2016-07-25T21:49:52.36Z"},
  {"PrimaryKey":333,"Date":"2016-09-03","Version":"9","Count":3,"Name":"iOS","LastAccessTime":"2016-08-22T21:49:52.36Z"},
  .....( *many values )
]}
```

The array `Detail` has lots of `PrimaryKey`s. Sometimes, it is about 500K `PrimaryKey`s. The system we use can only process JSON strings with certain length, i.e. 128KB. So I have to split this JSON string into segments (each one is 128KB or fewer chars in length).

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"\{"".{0," + (128*1024).ToString() + @"}""\}");
MatchCollection mc = reg.Matches(myListString);
```

Currently, I use regular expression to do this. It works fine. However, it uses too much memory. Is there a better way to do this (unnecessary to be regular expression)?

*** Added more info.

**The 'system' I mentioned above is Azure DocumentDB. By default, the document can only be 512KB (as now). Although we can request MS increase this, but the json file we got always much much more than 512KB. That's why we need to figure out a way to do this.**

If possible, we want to keep using documentDB, but we are open to other suggestions.

*** Some info to make things clear: 1) the values in the array are different. Not duplicated. 2) Yes, I use StringBuilder whenever I can. 3) Yes, I tried IndexOf & Substring, but based on tests, the performance is not better than regular expression in this case (although it could be the way I implement it).

*** **the json object is complex, but all I care is this "Detail" which is an array. We can assume the string is just like the example, only has "Detail". We need to split this json array string into size smaller than 512KB. Basically, we can think this as a simple string, not json. but, it is a json format, so maybe some libraries can do this better.**

Comment: What System? (The system we use can only process the json string wiht certain length, i.e. 128KB)

Comment: You will essentially have to rewrite your json to be valid json of lesser length, or is the "system" you're talking about homebrew and doesn't really care if it is valid json or not? Why not take a look at json.net or something that doesn't have this kind of limitation?

Comment: If you know the exact format of your data and don't care about breaking the parsing code if the format changes, I think a couple of `IndexOf` and `Substring` would do the trick.

Comment: Well, you have 3 lines of *duplicated* data. What if you make *one* line instead as a Key `"PrimaryKey":null,"Date":"2016-09-06","Version":"7","Count":2,"Name":"Windows"`, and array or collection of dates as Value

Comment: @Fabjan, are you serious? It's obvious that the JSON objects will be different in production. OP *obviously* just copy and pasted the same line for exemplary purposes.

Comment: For a overall better perfomance in your whole project please consider to only user StringBuilder in C# not String

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I am not sure if it is the case. OP said nothing that indicates that real world example is different. On contrary, how the data structure in this example is organized it is likely that there might be tons of duplicated data. When one asks questions on SO he would better decribe problem as precise as it's possible as well as his attempts of solving it. Does OP google'd it at all ?

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited the question to make things clear. 1) the values in the array are different. Not duplicated. 2) Yes, I use StringBuilder whenever I can. 3) Yes, I tried IndexOf & Substring, but based on tests, the performance is not better than regular expression in this case (although it could be the way I implement it).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`Json.NET`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) (available via NuGet).

It has a `JsonReader` class, which allows you to create a required object by reading json by token, [example of json reading with `JsonReader`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/readjsonwithjsontextreader.htm). Not that if you pass invalid json string (e.g. without "end array" character or without "end object" character) to `JsonReader` - it will throw an exception only when it reaches invalid item, so you can pass different substrings to it.

Also, I guess that your system has something similar to `JsonReader`, so you can use it.

Reading a `string` with `StringReader` should not require too much application memory and it should be faster then iterating through regular expression matches.

Comment: JsonReader won't work better in this case. Because the json string for the array is very long, now we want to split them into multiple string, each less than 512KB. This means we need to loop through the objects, figure out the element's length, add them until the string reached 512KB, output the string, then processing the next object. This is obviously slower than processing the string by IndexOf directly, since we do not need to parse the object. And IndexOf is slower than regex in this case based on tests. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hacky solution assuming `data` contains your JSON data:

```
var details = data
    .Split('[')[1]
    .Split(']')[0]
    .Split(new[] { "}," }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(d => d.Trim())
    .Select(d => d.EndsWith("}") ? d : d + "}");;

foreach (var detail in details)
{
    // Now process "detail" with your JSON library.
}
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sBQjyi

Obviously you should only do this if you really can't use a normal JSON library. See [Mikhail Neofitov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39525678/1025555) for library suggestions.

If you are reading the JSON data from file or network you should implement a more stream-like processing where you read one details line, deserialize it with your JSON library and yield it to the caller. When the caller requests the next detail object, read the next line, deserialize it and so on. This way you can minimize the memory footprint of your deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider storing each detail in a separate document. It means two round trips to get both the header and all of the detail documents, but it means you are never dealing with a really large JSON document. Also, if Detail is added to incrementally, it'll be much more efficient for writes because there is no way to just add another row. You have to rewrite the entire document. Your read/write ratio will determine the break even point in overall efficiency.

Another argument for this is that the complexity of regex parsing, feeding it through your JSON parser, then reassembling it goes away. You never know if your regex parser will deal with all cases (commas inside of quotes, international characters, etc.). I've seen many folks think they have a good regex only to find odd cases in production.

If your Detail array can grow unbounded (or even with a large bound), then you should definitely make this change regardless of your JSON parser limitations or read/write ratio because eventually, you'll exceed the limit.

Comment: Thank larry！You are 100% correct. The regex won't be able to deal with all possibilities. But that's not my concern yet. As for saving a detail as document, actually, that's the 'next' issue I need to solve. We want to add more to Detail array over time, but since we have so much data, eventually, it may have more document than one collection allows. So we decided to assume no-add in Detail for now. Now, if we save each element in Detail as a document, it will have performance issue since we will need to get hundreds of thousands documents when we need to use the Detail.

Comment: I strongly recommend using partitioned collections now-a-days so you shouldn't worry about it outgrowing a single collection. I would not assume that it would be any slower to gather the details when they are all in their own document. Sure, it takes one round trip for the header and another for the details, but the overall read might not be as big a difference as you think. Also, the writes will be much faster this way especially if you add details later.